Convert Creole List Formatting to HTML with PHP / RegEx
I have a small problem that I, my colleagues and ChatGPT are not really getting anywhere with.
I have to change a creole formatting with PHP (Laravel Framework) to HTML. I wanted to do this with RegEx because external systems are unfortunately not an option. Unfortunately, the formatting cannot be changed either because it is a manufacturer specification.
The goal is (I have no problem with this):
- - - - in <hr>
**text** in <b>text</b>
\\ in <br>

And now comes the thing that I have a problem with:
* foo\\ * bar\\ must be in <ul><li>foo</li><li>bar</li></ul>

As there can always be several lists in the entire text, these must of course not be grouped together and the function must not be mentioned if an * appears in the text because there is a possibility that this will happen.
I would be very grateful for help and thank you in advance.
Edit:
External libraries are not an option because we already have two installed that do something similar and this should only be used in one place in the code.

Does this answer your question? How can I convert markdown to html (should i use an existing script)?

Why wouldnt you be able to use any of these https://packagist.org/search/?tags=creole?

Sorry, I forgot to write that external libraries are not an option. But thanks for your help.
